# How to add two index in ng-options ans set the value dynamically using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need one help.i need to two index(`i.e-$index,$parent.$index`) in ng-options object using Angular.js.I am explaining my code below.

```
<tr ng-repeat="d in days">
        <td>{{d.day_name}}</td>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="answer in d.answers">
                <td>
                  <select class="form-control" id="answer_{{$index}}_{{$parent.$index}}_category" name="answer_{{$index}}_category" ng-model="answer.catagory" ng-options="cat.name for cat in listOfCatagory track by cat.value" ng-change="removeBorder($index,answer.catagory.value,$parent.$index);">
                    <option value="">Select Category</option>
                  </select>
                </td>
                 </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          </td>
          <td>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="answer in d.answers">
                <td>
                  <select class="form-control" id="answer_{{$index}}_{{$parent.$index}}_subcategory" name="answer_{{$index}}_subcategory" ng-model="answer.subcatagory" ng-options="sub.name for sub in listOfSubCatagory[$index+$parent.$index] track by sub.value">
                    <option value="">Select Subcategory</option>
                  </select>
                </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          </td>
          <td>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="answer in d.answers">
                <td>
                  <input type="text" id="answer_{{$index}}_{{$parent.$index}}_comment" name="answer_{{$index}}_comment" placeholder="Add Comment" ng-model="answers.comment">
                </td>

          </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          </td>
          <td>
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="answer in d.answers">
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="plus" id="plus" value="+" style="width:20px; text-align:center;" ng-click="addNewRow(d.answers, true)">
                    <div ng-show="$first && !$last">
                     <input type="submit" name="minus" id="minus" value="-" style="width:20px; text-align:center;" ng-click="removeRow(d.answers, $last)">
                     </div>
                </td>
          </tr>
```

here i need to pass two index with `listOfSubCatagory` so that i can set multi-dimentional   data dynamically .i did some coading but its not working as per requirement.I am explaining my controller side code below.

```
$scope.listOfSubCatagory = []; 
  $scope.removeBorder=function(index,catvalue,parent){
      console.log('ind',index,catvalue,parent);
     $scope.listOfSubCatagory[index+parent]=[];
     var catdata=$.param({'action':'subcat','cat_id':catvalue});
        $http({
            method:'POST',
            url:"php/customerInfo.php",
            data:catdata,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).then(function successCallback(response){
            angular.forEach(response.data,function(obj){
                var data={'name':obj.subcat_name,'value':obj.subcat_id};
                $scope.listOfSubCatagory[index+parent].push(data);
            })
        },function errorCallback(response) {
        }) 
  }

$scope.days=[];
    $http({
        method:'GET',
        url:"php/customerInfo.php?action=day",
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    }).then(function successCallback(response){
        //console.log('day',response.data);
         angular.forEach(response.data, function(obj) {
      obj.answers = [];
      $scope.addNewRow(obj.answers);
      $scope.days.push(obj);
    });
    },function errorCallback(response) {
    })
    }
     $scope.addNewRow = function(answers, hasDelete) {
    answers.push({
      category: null,
      subcategory: null,
      comment: null,
      hasDelete: hasDelete ? hasDelete : false
    });
  };

  $scope.removeRow = function(answers, $index){
    answers.splice($index, 1);
  };
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: This code seems to be quite familiar. Would you like to explain more, what exactly you want to do ?

Comment: @AnkitPundhir : Ok,here i have one functionalty add button when user is clicking that more row is adding  for same day.Here my requirement is if i am selecting the any category from any day the subcategory should set in only that row subcategory list not in other day subcatagory list.As i have multiple row in same day i am facing problem.

Comment: I don't think you may require 3 ng-repeats inside. It can be done with 1 ng-repeat inside. You can go through my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated my plunker code for you. If you use similar approach then you may get required results.
Sorry for my spell mistakes in earlier `plunk`. I improved them now.
You can go through and update your code accordingly,

https://plnkr.co/edit/Px7vY4?p=preview

Comment: you can check this answer it is not coming in proper order as per column.its showing all under category section.

Comment: Oky i got it... i did't realise that. apologies for that, anyways it will be better to use bootstrap ul-li grid rather than a table design. But for your case I updated that plunker. Thanks ;)

Comment: ok sure,its good now but all catagory should come under only category and subcategory should come under subcategory and comment like this.

Comment: I didn't got you this time? Can you explain more. Because now i can see all columns aligned properly :P

Comment: Let me to check now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106695/discussion-between-subhra-and-ankit-pundhir).

Comment: but you are setting subcatagory field globaly where its depends on catagory.

Comment: you can check `$scope.removeBorder` method... I just created an emulated response... it should be removed with actual server response... I just written an idea, not just the whole code. Because I don't know how exactly your ajax call structure is. Anyways I hope it would helped you to overcome your issue.